# Trying to make a function that returns a 2D array, with using switch inside the function. Getting the "Duplicate local variable <board>" warning

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, switch-statement

I'm writing a simple program that displays a 2D array. User will be given 4 options to choose from, but for simplicity sakes of this question, I rewrote the program so there's only 2 option enclosed in the switch, and that the second option will always be chosen. The code does not print anything, it only prints "This is your array :". I'm seeing "Duplicate local variable board" in my errors page but I do not know how to fix this.

Here is my code:

```java
public class Apples {
    static char[][] createBoard(int boardType) {
        char[][] board = new char[8][10];
        switch (boardType) {
            case 1:
                char board[][] = {
                        {' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'},
                        {'1', '#', '#', '#', '-', '@', '-', '#', '#', '#'},
                        {'2', '#', '#', '-', '@', '@', '@', '-', '#', '#'},
                        {'3', '#', '-', '@', '@', '-', '@', '@', '-', '#'},
                        {'4', '-', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@', '-'}};
                break;
            case 2:
                char board[][] = {
                        {' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'},
                        {'1', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'},
                        {'2', '-', '@', '@', '@', '-'},
                        {'3', '-', '-', '@', '-', '-'},
                        {'4', '-', '-', '@', '-', '-'},
                        {'5', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'}};
                break;
        }
        return board;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("This is your array :");

        char chosenboard[][] = createBoard(2);
        for (int row = 0; row < chosenboard.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < chosenboard[row].length; column++) {
                System.out.print(chosenboard[row][column]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second attempt : doing "declare first, initialize later":

```java
public class Apples {
    static char[][] createBoard(int boardType) {
        char[][] board;
        switch (boardType) {
            case 1:
                board = new char[][]{
                        {' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'},
                        {'1', '#', '#', '#', '-', '@', '-', '#', '#', '#'},
                        {'2', '#', '#', '-', '@', '@', '@', '-', '#', '#'},
                        {'3', '#', '-', '@', '@', '-', '@', '@', '-', '#'},
                        {'4', '-', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@', '-'}};
                break;
            case 2:
                board = new char[][]{
                        {' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'},
                        {'1', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'},
                        {'2', '-', '@', '@', '@', '-'},
                        {'3', '-', '-', '@', '-', '-'},
                        {'4', '-', '-', '@', '-', '-'},
                        {'5', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'}};
                //here I am declaring and assigning again
                break;

        }
        return board;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("This is your array :");
        char chosenboard[][] = createBoard(2);
        for (int row = 0; row < chosenboard.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < chosenboard[row].length; column++) {
                System.out.print(chosenboard[row][column]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The previous error of "duplicate local variable" went away, but I got a new error on my return board line. It says the "the local variable board may not have been initialized"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not compile because the variable `board` is already defined before the switch statement and cannot be defined again (in that scope).

```java
static char[][] createBoard(int boardType) {
  char[][] board = new char[8][10];          // <= declared and assigned
  switch (boardType) {
    case 1:
      char board[][] = {{' ', /* ... */ }};  // <= declared and assigned again
      break;
    // ...
```

Inside the case you can create a new 2d-array and then assign it to the already declared variable like this:

```java
char[][] board; // declaration
board = new char[][]{{' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}, {'1', '#', '#', '#', '-', '@', '-', '#', '#', '#'}, {'2', '#', '#', '-', '@', '@', '@', '-', '#', '#'}, {'3', '#', '-', '@', '@', '-', '@', '@', '-', '#'}, {'4', '-', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@', '-'}};
```

---

Looking a bit closer what your method `createBoard` does, you could simplify this further and directly construct and return the 2d-array:

```java
static char[][] createBoard(int boardType) {
    switch (boardType) {
        case 1:
            return new char[][]{{' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}, {'1', '#', '#', '#', '-', '@', '-', '#', '#', '#'}, {'2', '#', '#', '-', '@', '@', '@', '-', '#', '#'}, {'3', '#', '-', '@', '@', '-', '@', '@', '-', '#'}, {'4', '-', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@', '-'}};
        case 2:
            return new char[][]{{' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'}, {'1', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'}, {'2', '-', '@', '@', '@', '-'}, {'3', '-', '-', '@', '-', '-'}, {'4', '-', '-', '@', '-', '-'}, {'5', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'}};
        default:
            return new char [8][10];
    }
}
```

---

Addressing your edit to the question which added a second attempt:
The error means that you are trying to return `board` but it might have not been initialised. In your case, if the input is not 1 or 2, there is no assignment to `board`. You can add a default case to the switch-statement to solve this. Or assign a default value when you declare the variable.

Comment: is there a way for us to *declare* an array, then *define* it later? Like how we do with some normal primitive type variables

Comment: @kai Yes, that is exactly what I show in my answer (now made a bit clearer). You declare first and then assign later. The special syntax `int x[] = {1,2,3}` is called *array initializer* and only works when you declare and assign at the same time. For later assignment, you need to use `x = new int[]{1,2,3}` (constructor).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. I've thought of returning in every case statement too but apparently I saw from another question here on stackoverflow that returning after each case is a bad programming practice. I followed the idea of declaring first, defining later, and the error went away, but I got a new error at the line ```return board```. Would appreciate if you'd take a look at it for me, I'll put edit my question and put the code there.

Comment: @kai I just edited the question to address your second attempt. It is an arguable point concerning returns in switch-cases and it depends on the programming language and the purpose of the method. I see nothing wrong in this case to return early, as no resources need to be cleaned up and your method has only one purpose (return the board depending on the input value). Always challenge things you read about good/bad practice and consult multiple resources to understand the reasons behind these recommendations. This will help you when you need to make such decisions in the future.

Comment: Aight thanks for the advice. Anyways my program now works if I add the default statement to my code in "attempt 2". But out of curiosity, I tried the "returning new char in every case" way you posted just now. The program runs but it does not print out the array. All it printed out was "This is your array  ". I then added a println line before the return statement in each case saying "Hi, this is case 1", and "Hi, this is case 2" to see if the cases are actually ran. When I call the function with putting 1 in its arguments, I got the "Hi this is case 1", but it did not print out the array.

Comment: Is it too confusing to understand for you? I can post another question, put the code there and tag you if that helps

Comment: @kai I just tested my answer completely and it works as expected. If you have another problem, it's best to ask a new question since this problem here seems to be solved.

Comment: wait what I copied the entire code into a new class, compiled it and it somehow worked this time. It was a glitch maybe, thanks anyways!